# R: how to change list into vector of dataframe after sapply?

Tags: r, list, function, apply, sapply

I made a function called `my_title()` that tries to match through every name under `title$Name` to find a match, where it will return the title in that name if it is one of the titles considered or "Other" if it's not.

```
name_exp <- c("Miss.", "Mrs.", "Mr.", "Master.", "Dr.", "Rev.")
my_title <- function(x){
  i <- 1
  for(i in 1:length(name_exp)){
    full_name <- paste(name_exp[i])
    name_check <- grepl(x, pattern=full_name)
    if(name_check=="TRUE"){
      nmatches <- gregexpr(pattern=full_name, text=x[name_check])
      finalnames <- regmatches(x[[name_check]], nmatches)
      return(finalnames)
    }
    else{
      if(i==6 & name_check=="FALSE"){
      return("Other")
      }
      else{
        i <- i+1
      }
  }
  }
}
```

However, the next step is to create a new column in the dataframe `titanic$Title` where each one matches the corresponding output from the function. I used `sapply()` but the return is a list, not a vector of characters. Ideally, `titanic$Title[1]` would return the title "Mr." and not `<chr [1]>`.

I tried to use `unlist()` but I get errors. Not sure how to proceed, thank you!

```
titanic$Title <- sapply(titanic$Name, my_title)
titanic[sample(1:nrow(titanic),10),c("Title","Name")]
```

so when I test this using the second line above, I get this:

```
Title
<list>
Name
<chr>
792 <chr [1]>   Gaskell, Mr. Alfred     
570 <chr [1]>   Jonsson, Mr. Carl       
873 <chr [1]>   Carlsson, Mr. Frans Olof        
674 <chr [1]>   Wilhelms, Mr. Charles       
224 <chr [1]>   Nenkoff, Mr. Christo        
673 <chr [1]>   Mitchell, Mr. Henry Michael     
198 <chr [1]>   Olsen, Mr. Karl Siegwart Andreas        
119 <chr [1]>   Baxter, Mr. Quigg Edmond        
866 <chr [1]>   Bystrom, Mrs. (Karolina)        
242 <chr [1]>   Murphy, Miss. Katherine "Kate"
```

Running the `head(titanic$Title)`:

```
$`Braund, Mr. Owen Harris`
[1] "Mr."

$`Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)`
[1] "Mrs."

$`Heikkinen, Miss. Laina`
[1] "Miss."
```

Comment: It would help if you could include some example data that demonstrates the issue.  For example, I have no problems when I create the data.frame titanic as follows:  `titanic <- data.frame(Name=c('Mr. Foo', 'Master. Bob'))`

Comment: What error do you get if you try `titanic$Title <- unlist(sapply(titanic$Name, my_title))`?